# Why can't I install VirtualBox-guest additions on my fedora 17 system?

Tags: virtualbox, fedora-17

I am trying to install the Virtualbox-guest additions, and get an error:

```
# yum install VirtualBox-guest
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package VirtualBox-guest.x86_64 0:4.2.6-5.fc17 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: VirtualBox-4.2.6-5.fc17.x86_64 conflicts VirtualBox-guest <= 4.2.6-5.fc17
--> Processing Conflict: VirtualBox-guest-4.2.6-5.fc17.x86_64 conflicts VirtualBox <= 4.2.6-5.fc17
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

# yum list installed|grep Virtual
VirtualBox.x86_64                       4.2.6-5.fc17                 @rpmfusion-free-updates
```

Why won't this install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here:

> --> Processing Conflict: VirtualBox-4.2.6-5.fc17.x86_64 conflicts VirtualBox-guest <= 4.2.6-5.fc17
>   --> Processing Conflict: VirtualBox-guest-4.2.6-5.fc17.x86_64 conflicts VirtualBox <= 4.2.6-5.fc17

remove `Virtualbox` `VirtualBox-guest` already installed on your system, then try again.

you have non-x64 virtualbox installed, and are trying to install x64 virtualbox.